# How can I use the same fill colour for same category on different ggplot column plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset which has a variable "Kategorie". From that dataset I need to create different plots, based on some filter and grouping. I created a vector which maps the Kategorie values to the colours I have choosen for them, to be used as fill with `scale_fill_manual`. Additionally I want to reorder the X axis, depending on the categories value, like in a scree plot, biggest category left, smallest category right. As I have another variable with two values, I came across a `facet_grid` on that variable. But ordering of the X axis was not working. Thus I came across `grid.arrange` and `subset`. X axis ordering is fine now.
But the issue I face now is that the colour is not consistent on the categories on the two facets. How can I get consistent colours for categories amongst different plots, either created within one ggplot call with facets or with separate ggplot calls?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(gridExtra)

options(dplyr.summarise.inform = FALSE)

human_numbers <- function(x = NULL,
                          smbl = "",
                          signif = 1) {
  humanity <- function(y) {
    if (!is.na(y)) {
      tn <- round(abs(y) / 1e12, signif)
      b <- round(abs(y) / 1e9, signif)
      m <- round(abs(y) / 1e6, signif)
      k <- round(abs(y) / 1e3, signif)
      
      if (y >= 0) {
        y_is_positive <- ""
      } else {
        y_is_positive <- "-"
      }
      
      if (k < 1) {
        paste0(y_is_positive, smbl, round(abs(y), signif))
      } else if (m < 1) {
        paste0 (y_is_positive, smbl,  k , "k")
      } else if (b < 1) {
        paste0 (y_is_positive, smbl, m , "m")
      } else if (tn < 1) {
        paste0 (y_is_positive, smbl, b , "bn")
      } else {
        paste0 (y_is_positive, smbl,  comma(tn), "tn")
      }
    } else if (is.na(y) | is.null(y)) {
      "-"
    }
  }
  
  sapply(x, humanity)
}

human_euro  <- function(x){human_numbers(x, smbl = "\u20AC")} 
human_num   <- function(x){human_numbers(x, smbl = "")} 

x <- structure(list(Wer = c("Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", 
                            "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", 
                            "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt1", "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", 
                            "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", 
                            "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2", "Abt2"), 
                    Kategorie = c("Kategorie 1", 
                                  "Kategorie 2", "Kategorie 3", "Kategorie 4", "Kategorie 5", "Kategorie 6", 
                                  "Kategorie 7", "Kategorie 8", "Kategorie 9", "Kategorie 10", "Kategorie 11", "Kategorie 12", 
                                  "Kategorie 13", "Kategorie 14", "Kategorie 15", "Kategorie 1", "Kategorie 16", "Kategorie 2", 
                                  "Kategorie 9", "Kategorie 5", "Kategorie 7", "Kategorie 13", "Kategorie 3", 
                                  "Kategorie 10", "Kategorie 6", "Kategorie 8", "Kategorie 17", "Kategorie 14", 
                                  "Kategorie 11", "Kategorie 15", "Kategorie 12"), 
                    Wert = c(9130, 8974.06, 
                             7973.7, 5151.84, 4442.31, 2199.6, 2174.53, 1694.6, 938.46, 587.85, 
                             441.1, 419.69, 196.54, 115.44, 16.85, 24775, 11660.44, 10666.48, 
                             6881.8, 3958.39, 2144.34, 1609.53, 1500.77, 1405, 986.4, 882.89, 
                             812.7, 798.68, 336.29, 235.12, 12.3), 
                    Anteil = c(20.5, 20.2, 
                               17.9, 11.6, 10, 4.9, 4.9, 3.8, 2.1, 1.3, 1, 0.9, 0.4, 0.3, 0, 
                               36.1, 17, 15.5, 10, 5.8, 3.1, 2.3, 2.2, 2, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 
                               0.5, 0.3, 0)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -31L), 
               groups = structure(
                 list(
                   Wer = c("Abt1", "Abt2"), 
                   .rows = structure(
                     list(1:15, 16:31), 
                     ptype = integer(0), 
                     class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))
                 ), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 .drop = TRUE
               ), 
               class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

color_palette <- c(
  "dodgerblue2", 
  "#E31A1C", # red
  "green4",
  "#6A3D9A", # purple
  "#FF7F00", # orange
  "black", 
  #"gold1",
  "skyblue2", 
  "#FB9A99", # lt pink
  "palegreen2",
  #"#CAB2D6", # lt purple
  "#FDBF6F", # lt orange
  "gray70", 
  #"khaki2",
  "maroon", 
  "orchid1", 
  #"deeppink1", 
  "blue1", 
  "steelblue4",
  "darkturquoise", 
  "green1", 
  #"yellow4", 
  "yellow3",
  #"darkorange4", 
  "brown4"
)

names(color_palette) <- levels(unique(x$Kategorie))

q1 <- x %>% subset(Wer == 'Abt1') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Kategorie, -Wert), y=Wert, fill=Kategorie)) +
  geom_col(width=0.6) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Wer) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::comma(Anteil, big.mark='.', decimal.mark=',', suffix='%')), vjust=-0.1, hjust=-0.1, angle=60, color="black", size=4) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = human_euro) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Kategorie", values = color_palette) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

q2 <- q1 %+% subset(x, Wer == 'Abt2')

grid.arrange(q1, q2, nrow=1)
```

With this code the output looks like this. Notice that "Kategorie 2" and "Kategorie 16" share the same colour, but they should have different colours.

[image: Plot with facets]

Answer (score 1):

you can set up a common scale like this (example data):

```
categories = c('a long label',
               'another long label',
               'not short either'
               )

d1 <- data.frame(source = 1, cat = head(categories, 2), value = 1:2)
d2 <- data.frame(source = 2, cat = tail(categories, 2), value = 4:5)

my_scale <- scale_fill_manual(
  breaks = categories,
  values = c('red', 'blue', 'green')
)

p1 <- ggplot(d1) +  geom_col(aes(cat, value, fill = cat)) + my_scale
p2 <- ggplot(d2) +  geom_col(aes(cat, value, fill = cat)) + my_scale

p1 + p2
```

[image: more chart junk]
note, however, that this will make it much harder for the reader to compare categories (or even read the labels) than simply aligning categories like this:

```
bind_rows(d1, d2) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(cat, value)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~ source)
```

[image: less chart junk]

Comment: unfortunately this did not work out on my example. I created a vector `categories <- unique(x$Kategorie)` which contains the 17 categories, and assigned it to the `breaks` parameter on `scale_fill_manual`. The result is the same like before.

Comment: you could try a named vector, created with `setNames` and inserted like this: `scale_fill_discrete(values = setNames(unique(x$Kategorie), c('red', 'blue' # rest of colours)), ...)`

Comment: I had to replace the `values` parameter by `breaks` in order for `scale_fill_discrete` to be called. But the colours I provided were not used, instead the viridis colour palette is used I guess. And the colour used e.g. for Kategorie 2 is different.

Comment: Now I could manage to get the same colour fill for the same categories. I created the named vector wrong: `names(color_palette) <- levels(unique(x$Kategorie))` instead of `color_palette <- c('Kategorie 1' = 'color1', 'Kategorie 2' = 'color2', ...)`. Using `scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette)` leads to consistent colours for the categories.